# What is + in Linux file/direcory permission column?

Tags: linux, redhat

Recently when I was surfing around the /var/log directory I've noticed some directory has a '+' symbol in the file permission column while other have a '.' (dot) in their file permission column. Does anyone know what the '.' (dot) or '+' means in the file permission?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from `man acl`:

> •   For files that have a default ACL or an access ACL that contains more than the three required ACL entries, the ls(1) utility in the long form produced by `ls -l` displays a plus sign (+) after the permission string.

i.e. it means Access Control Lists in effect.